# Flutter App cannot be released for Android TV

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, android-tv

I'm building a Flutter app that should support Android TV and Mobile devices.
Despite Google Play reject release, I can install my app on my MiBox device.

[image: Supported devices on play store]

While trying to install it, both Androdi TV devices are shown as not available.

[image]

***Note: I need camera permission mobile, but not TV device;***

*At the same time, I can install and run the app on Android TV via ADB.*

While uploading a new build to play store, I see next details:

[image]

**Android Manifest:**

```
<!--  Android TV support  -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor" android:required="false"/>
...
android:banner="@drawable/banner"
... 
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

**build.gradle**

```
    minSdkVersion 23
    compileSdkVersion 33
    targetSdkVersion 33
```

***UPDATE:***

I missed the point that my app was rejected by the review:
[image]

*I tested the very same APK on Android TV MiBox and it works fine*

I tried `bundletool` to install the release bundle to my MiBox and it also works file:

```
java -jar "bundletool.jar" build-apks --bundle="/build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab" --output="app.apks"
java -jar "bundletool.jar" install-apks --apks=app.apks
```

I tried to test it with Firebase Test Lab, but somehow it shows device are incompatible:

[image]

From build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ndk {
                // Filter for architectures supported by Flutter.
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
            }
        }
    }
```

[App link on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thedeck.app)

Comment: On the Goole Play Console, look in Release > Setup > Advanced Settings > Form factors (tab) - did you add or opt-in to "Android TV"?

Comment: Yes, actually I figure out that release to TV was rejected, but the rejection reason doesn't make sense "App Crash" even tho there are no crashes and I cannot reproduce it on any of real TV devices.

Comment: Have you tested your app in Release mode with minification/R8 enabled? how about on a real device?

Comment: I tried with a fat APK on the MiBox: fvm flutter build apk --release

Comment: For play store I'm using app bundle: fvm flutter build appbundle --release

Comment: Following advice from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48109 tried to switch the order of `intent.category`

Comment: Still rejected...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that google is forcing to migrate to app bundle instead of using apk.

so, either you should remove this line:

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
```

from manifests. or migrate to app bundle.

Comment: I'm already using an app bundle to release the app